# What's the missing pattern? 3x3 grid, dot pattern

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern, visual, geometry, no-computers

[image: Circle pattern puzzle]

What is the missing piece to this pattern? Got it as a quiz at work - no one here knows what it is!

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> It's a digital representation of the digits from 1 to 9. Each dot represents the corresponding line in the traditional digital representation.

This can be clearly seen in the following image:

> [image]

So the number 9 is represented by:

> [image: Answer]

Comment: Can you explain the digital represantation a bit more ?I can't see it in this circle

Comment: @O.Rares the dots directly correspond to a seven-segment display, like what you'll find on many digital clocks. If you stretch the dots out so that they look more like those clocks' displays, it should be easier to spot the pattern.

Comment: @Phlarx Thanks,I also posted a solution but it fades near yours

Comment: This seems to make sense to be, besides what is supposed to be the "4". Unless its rotated...

Comment: No, the 4 is correct. Had to check on my digital watch!

Comment: I added a stretched image to make it more clear ^-^

Comment: Great work. That makes it super clear

Comment: The orientation of the first pattern in the second row does not make sense to me. It seems to me like it would be more consistent with the others if rotated around the center dot 120 degrees counter-clockwise.

Comment: @Poosh, compare the stretched diagram with the numbers shown here: http://www.online-stopwatch.com/online-digital-clock/

Comment: @DrXorile, thanks! Now I get what the "stretching the dots" comment meant. (Hadn't reloaded the page and seen the image in the answer since I started puzzling over it a couple of days ago)

Answer (score 0):

> I see a pattern as a tool to make cookies
>
>  [image]
>
>  So we need to find a new cookie type.
>
>  At begin I saw there wasn't the one white dot and the white dot pattern in the center only.
>
>  As I looked closer at all patterns I can say that all can be rotated to change the black dots position in order to give a different perspective to the cookie lovers in order to sell them.
>
>  As I write this answer I see second pattern of first and second row are the same.That maybe,maybe not ,can confirm the rotation rule.
>
>  My guess is
>
>  [image: Bam]
>
>  I eliminated each time a black dot and created different patterns and compared with the existing one to get those